# Solr search for a site depoyed on web farm?

Tags: solr, solrnet

Is Lucene Solr works with web farm with load balancing server. I'm looking to implement with asp.net mvc3 web application, and moving to web farm with load balancing server is the next in roadmap, so want to understand how to do it with solr?

Comment: Check out the Solr cloud features coming in Solr version 4. http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrCloud

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The front end makes HTTP requests to Solr to get search results. Any HTTP load balancer will work.

Most systems use a single master Solr server and multiple slaves. Documents are submitted to the master, where they are analyzed and the search indexes created. The slaves poll the master and copy over new search indexes.

The Solr web site has a lot of information: http://lucene.apache.org/solr/

Comment: Hi, I didn't completely understand when you say "Most systems use a single master Solr server and multiple slaves."? Can you pls describe what you mean by this and how its relevant to load balancer?